# Vimeo video link regex

Tags: php, jquery, html, vimeo

Anybody got the regex for vimeo video links to extract them from a pragraph for use in php?  Can't seem to find a proper one for the latest vimeo url scheme

Comment: What is the latest Vimeo URL scheme?

Comment: Links of the type: http://vimeo.com/11339453

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the scheme is just `http://vimeo.com/A_NUMBER`, so try `http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\d+)`. If you don't need links to be prefixed by `http://`, you can leave off the whole `http://(www\.)` bit.

Comment: I'm replacing your regex in the preg_replace function, but getting an error: $content = preg_replace('http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\d+)', '[vimeo=$1]', $content);

Comment: If you're getting an error message, can you post it? Otherwise, if it's just giving empty output, try $2 - the `(www\.)?` might give an empty capture.

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\xampp\htdocs\functionr\media.php on line 5

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\functionr\media.php:5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\functionr\post_comment.php on line 11

Comment: changed to $s2, same problem.

Comment: Ah right. `preg_replace` needs delimeters to be placed round the regex - try `preg_replace('#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\d+)#g', '[vimeo=$1]', $content);`.

Comment: Another error this time: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'g' in C:\xampp\htdocs\functionr\media.php on line 5

Comment: btw, if it helps, I already have another regex in the same function: $content = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/www\.youtube[^ ]*)/', '[youtube=$1]', $content);

Comment: Sorry; take the `g` away from after the last `#`. Normally, the convention is to use `/REGEX/`, but as this regex needs to match slashes, it's simpler to use something else (like, here, `#REGEX#`) so the slashes don't need to be escaped (the `\/` stuff).

Comment: thanks...works perfectly now.  I'm lame in regex...so your help was invaluale! :)

Answer (score 12):

Vimeo have 4 different public video links

1. Video ID `vimeo.com/[Video ID]`
2. Channels `vimeo.com/channels/[Channel]/[Video ID]`
3. Groups `vimeo.com/groups/[Group]/[Video ID]`
4. Player `player.vimeo.com/video/[Video ID]`

`/(http|https)?:\/\/(www\.|player\.)?vimeo\.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:|\/\?)/`

Answer (score 4):

This one covers all possible Vimeo Video URL Schemes:

```
(?:http|https)?:?\/?\/?(?:www\.)?(?:player\.)?vimeo\.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)?|groups\/(?:[^\/]*)\/videos\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:|\/\?)
```

```
vimeo.com/123456789
vimeo.com/channels/mychannel/123456789
vimeo.com/groups/shortfilms/videos/123456789
player.vimeo.com/video/123456789
http://vimeo.com/123456789
https://vimeo.com/channels/mychannel/123456789
https://vimeo.com/groups/shortfilms/videos/123456789
https://www.player.vimeo.com/video/123456789
```

**Test here**:
https://regexr.com/68gk3

Answer (score 3):

Be careful:  The url scheme is

```
http://vimeo.com/[SEVERAL_FOLDERS(opt.)]/[VIDEO_NUMBER]
```

for example:

```
http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/48237094
http://vimeo.com/48237094
```

As you can see, it depends from what page the user copies the link from.

Comment: As of 2013, URLs for videos from partners have two letters and a dash: `http://vimeo.com/yt-9023jr28j04j` or `mu-` for muzu. So the ID should accept letters, numbers, and '-'.

Comment: then it would look like this I suppose: `http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\w*/)*(([a-z]{0,2}-)?\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with `vimeo\.com/(\d)+`? Do you need the `http://www.`?

Answer (score 0):

It's Better to ask viemo guys about it because they know better and if they change anything they will reflect it in their apis

Live Example :

[http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http%3A//vimeo.com/76979871](http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/76979871)

API docs : http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Answer inspired from this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156853/1545904