# PHP - Vimeo video detection for preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, vimeo

I'm trying to detect, whether my Vimeo link is in Vimeo format (http://www.vimeo.com/nnnnnnn)

I tried this:

```
preg_match("/http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/", $link);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Whats wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Be careful, vimeo has many different video formats. Some of these formats don't even include the ID in the url. For more information check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156298/get-id-video-vimeo-with-regexp-preg-match/17156853#17156853

Comment: Thanks, you have a point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com\/\d{8}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2pa

Comment: I have been searching SO for a while and I found out that it would be better to use 'preg_match("#https?://(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\w*/)*(([a-z]{0,2}-)?\d+)#", $link)' because it can be in this format `http://vimeo.com/[SEVERAL_FOLDERS(opt.)]/[VIDEO_CODE]` I have just modified your answer, though.

Comment: @ulkas: This should do it `preg_match("/https?:\/\/.*vimeo\.com\/.*\d+/", $input_line, $output_array);`

Comment: this answer could have been good a couple of years ago, this doesn't match all vimeo urls anymore. you could use a wider approach, like `/vimeo\.com\/(\w+\s*\/?)*([0-9]+)*$/i`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the pattern `https?://(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com/([0-9]{6,10})` for some time on a site. Seems to work.