# PHP regex to match Vimeo text OR html link

Tags: php, regex, youtube, vimeo

I'm looking for a PHP regex that will scan a block of text and match any Vimeo URLs--either as plain text or in HTML links, so I can replace them with embedded videos.

I have a version of each working, but I'm not skilled enough to augment them so that it'll do both, and a lot of the half-working ones I've found don't seem to account for the wrinkles listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12263701/1402052

The one that seems to effectively match HTML links:

```
$text = preg_replace('#(.*?)http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/([^ ?\n/]+)((\?|/).*?(\n|\s))?.*#x', '<div class="video vimeo"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$3" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>', $text);
```

The one that seems to effectively match plain text URLs:

```
$text = preg_replace('#http://(www\.)?vimeo\.com/(\d+)#', '<div class="video vimeo"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$2" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>', $text);
```

These also seem to work if I run *both* (the former first), but I'm guessing there's a much better way.

Also, I say "seems to" because I haven't stressed tested either sufficiently yet. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: So show what you've got. We're happy to help, but frankly, we get tired of people claiming they ALMOST something working and just need us to do everything for them anyways.

Comment: Edited. Sorry, I just assumed both were flawed enough that they'd provide little assistance.

Comment: doesn't matter if they're flawed or not... if they weren't you wouldn't be here, but it's nice to see that you actually TRIED doing this, instead of trying to get SO to do your job for you. There's far too many freeloaders out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart) here:

```
define( 
    'VIMEO_URL_PATTERN' ,
    '~https?://(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com/.*?/?(\d+)~i'
);
define(
    'URL_REPLACEMENT' ,
    '<div ... <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/$1...</div>'
);

$html = ... // Load HTML code here

// Change links
foreach($html->find('a') as $link) {
    if (
       preg_match(
            VIMEO_URL_PATTERN,
            $link->href,
            $matches
       )
    ) {
        $link->outertext = preg_replace( 
              VIMEO_URL_PATTERN,
              URL_REPLACEMENT,
              $link->href
        );
    }
}

// Change text
foreach($html->find('text') as $text) {
    $text->outertext = preg_replace(
           VIMEO_URL_PATTERN,
           URL_REPLACEMENT,
           $text
    );
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip--Simple HTML DOM looks pretty useful. I ended up running this block again (for YouTube as well), simply because my attempts to simply integrate it all into one loop produced some really wonky results, but it does technically work. I need to improve my RegEx to cover more URL possibilities, but I realize that's a separate question, so I'll mark this as answered. :)